# how to create two interfaces in ONE simulator and make them to communicate with each other?

Tags: networking, simulation

I have created two interfaces:

```
// "Bluetooth" interface for OBUs or cars    
btInterface.type = SimpleBroadcastInterface

// Transmit speed of 2 Mbps = 250kBps    
btInterface.transmitSpeed = 250k    
btInterface.transmitRange = 30

//for RSU    
highspeedInterface.type = SimpleBroadcastInterface    
highspeedInterface.transmitSpeed = 250k    
highspeedInterface.transmitRange = 40000
```

but RSU and OBU are not exchanging messages . i want RSU to receive message from OBU and forward it to destination OBU or to another RSU.

Please help me.

Comment: It would help if you could add more context, for instance:
- what software are you using?
- what is the simulator you are referring to?

Comment: I am using ONE simulator for Vehicular Delay Tolerant Network.